# Ubuntu 23.10 Gnome Setting ---> Ubuntu Desktop missing

Tags: gnome, settings, 23.10

I am missing the following setting:

[image: I am missing the following setting]

Can someone help me on that?

Comment: Has it ever worked? What changed, if it did? It's possible you're missing a package or two. Try `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` (note the caret (`^`) is important). It may install packages which should have been there, as part of Ubuntu.

Comment: It has never worked before. I have just done, as per your suggestion. But still is like that.

Comment: Is this actual Ubuntu 23.10 or some other derivative of Ubuntu, and not 'official' Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling the `ubuntu-settings`?  `sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-settings`

Comment: @popey It is the official iso from ubuntu.com